# how to generate agora token for audio/video call

Tags: ios, swift, agora.io

I have tried to generate agora token but can't get success to finding out the solution please help me out to find the solution

I have implemented this code for generating agora audio/video call token but there is no availability for this 'AgoraTokenbuilder' pod in official cocoa pods website please help me out to find the solution

```
func generateAgoraToken() -> String? {
    let appID = "YOUR_APP_ID" // Replace with your Agora App ID
    let appCertificate = "" // Leave empty if not using App Certificate
    let channelName = "yourChannelName" // Replace with your channel name
    let uid: UInt32 = 0 // Set to 0 for automatic UID assignment
    let expirationTimeInSeconds: TimeInterval = 3600 // Token expiration time (1 hour)

    let token = AgoraRtcTokenBuilder.buildToken(withAppId: appID, appCertificate: appCertificate, channelId: channelName, uid: uid, role: .publisher, expirationTimeInSeconds: UInt(expirationTimeInSeconds))

    return token
}
```